# Converting bar-codes to specific format using IF, FIND & MID function of excel

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel I have a number of columns containing barcodes of different types such as:

WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S9-P14     convert to  05-09-14

WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S8-P1      convert to  05-08-01

WS-S5-N-L1-C29-V-U16-S6-P6     convert to  16-06-06

I want to convert these to 8 characters using the following rules:

- remove the U and prefix 0 where appropriate
- remove S and prefix 0 where appropriate
- remove P and prefix 0 where appropriate

I believe there is a way to use IF,FIND & MID function to convert these in Excel but don't know how to start. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this does case 2 fine, but does not deal with P14 or U16, but you can take it further...

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)+1),"U",0),"S",0),"P",0)
```

assumed data was in cell A1 to A3, just drag down. Very brute force though...

[image]

Comment: I've used the following formula which returns "05" from the column WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S9-P14. But how do I return "05-09-14"?

=IF(MID(E13,FIND("-U",E13)+3,1)="-","0"&MID(E13,FIND("-U",E13)+2,1),MID(E13,FIND("-U",E13)+2,2))

Comment: great technique used but unfortunately, code does not deal with three characters as you mentioned.

Comment: @Indy I left it to you to take it further - should improve your skills...